# Convert or cast object[] to xml document and retrieve values from xml nodes

Tags: c#, .net, xml

1. What is the most optimized code for converting an object[] to an xml document?
   In a function from a service the return type is object [] and the object returned contains a list of xml elements. So I need to convert this object[] to xml for data retrieval.
2. Also what is the most optimized code for retrieving values from a particular node ( say node with name project) and values as list ( ABC, XYZ) by navigating through the xml document given?

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
 <ArrayOfAnyType xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <anyType>
 <attributes xmlns="http://services.abc.com">
   <attributes>
    <name>projectdetails</name> 
     <values>
      <values>ABC</values> 
      <values>XYZ</values> 
     </values>
   </attributes> 
  </anyType>
  </ArrayOfAnyType>`

Comment: Would need an example input/output to see what you mean. What does it *mean* to convert `object[]` to an xml document? Would also need example xml structure for the second part of the question.

Comment: edited, problem with markup indention.

Answer (score 0):

XMLSerializer does a pretty good job on serializing any objects.

No idea on optimized..it's .net..so it probably uses an optimal data structure for this(perhaps a b tree).

Here is an article on the topic.
http://robseder.wordpress.com/2010/03/18/the-deal-with-xmlserializer-being-so-slow-%E2%80%93-finally/

Comment: a b-tree has very little to do with serialization; serializers just walk the object graph. But until the OP clarifies, I'm not sure this question has much to do with serialization.